# Even Descartes numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

A **Descartes number** is [defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes_number) as *an odd number which would have been an odd perfect number, if one of its composite factors were prime*. An example is:

$$
D = 3^2\times7^2\times11^2\times13^2\times22021,
$$

for which the divisor sigma function equals $2D$ when $22021$ is assumed prime (which it is evidently not).

If one removes the requirement of being an odd number, one can find several examples of "*even Descartes numbers*". For instance, one observes that

$$
D_e = 3\times4\times5 = 60
$$

is such that $\sigma(D_e)=2D_e$ if one assumes that $4$ is prime. Indeed:

$$
\sigma(3\times5)\times(4+1) = 120 = 2D_e.
$$

I have not found any mention of *even Descartes numbers* in literature. Are these interesting for any reason, have they been studied anywhere? Any references would be welcome.

Comment: Such numbers are certainly interesting, but in the case of odd numbers, there is a clear motivation to search for numbers somehow coming near to a perfect number because no single odd perfect number is known.

Comment: @Peter Thank you. Do you know any papers that have dealt with "even Descartes numbers"? Or any mention of them in literature?

Comment: bump... so there are no such references?

Comment: I have not checked this. But as said, in the case of even numbers, the motivation is small because the perfect numbers are completely classified by the Mersenne-primes.

Comment: @Peter Thank you!

Comment: @Peter Is it sill interesting if I can generate an infinity of even Descartes numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descartes numbers (from its original formulation in Banks, et. al's paper) are also known as *spoof odd perfect numbers* (as coined by Dittmer).

In your case, the correct search term to use is *even spoof perfect number*.

Google returns the following references:

https://oeis.org/wiki/Spoof_perfect_numbers#Even_spoof_perfect_numbers

[Spoof odd perfect numbers by Dittmer](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2014-83-289/S0025-5718-2013-02793-7/home.html)

[Problems and Puzzles on Spoof Perfect Numbers](http://www.primepuzzles.net/puzzles/puzz_111.htm)

Comment: You can also try searching for references related to the *freestyle sum of divisors function*, @PreservedFruit.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Quick follow-up question: do we know whether there are an infinity of spoof-perfect numbers (or **odd** spoof-perfect numbers)? I found no reference to the density of such numbers in any of the links.

Comment: @Klangen: There is only one odd spoof-perfect number that is currently known, and you already have that number in your question. Many more even spoof-perfect numbers are known, but I do not know if we can prove that there are infu

Comment: (Cont'd.) ... infinitely* many of them.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Thank you.

Comment: @Klangen: It *is* conjectured that there are only *finitely* many even completely spoof-perfect numbers, for a given number of composite factors.  Check the last link in my answer.